# Java Swing - Creating a window with buttons and a dynamic game board

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I am new to Java Swing and am working on a simple application that displays a board game and movable pieces in a window.

Right now, I have a nice enough interface: the application is built on a special `Window` class derived from `JFrame`, with the `paint` method overridden to display the board and pieces using `drawImage` (iterating through the pieces to gather position information as it goes)

When I tried to add some buttons and text display areas to the overall game window, however, there was a problem. None of them were being displayed until they were explicitly clicked on. With a little research, I found that overriding the paint will mess things up in a case like this; apparently, you can mess with `paint` or use buttons, etc., but not really/easily both.

As an alternative approach, I came across a tutorial that shows how to paint an image onto a JPanel, which I suppose I could use on the board/pieces instead and then treat like any other button or widget when laying things out(?) Before I go down any dead-end streets (seems like a silly question, but believe me...), I want to ask: is this a good approach? Or is there a better way?

Comment: There should very few reasons to ever override the `paint` method of a top level container like `JFrame`, instead, as Reimeus has pointed out, use something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  Take a look at [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are not calling `super.paint(g)` from within your `paint` method. Really you shouldn't have custom paint functionality in a top level container like `JFrame`.

Ideally you should use that alternative approach and move it to a new `JComponent` based class . Here you need override `paintComponent` and also call `super.paintComponent(g)`. If you need to add child components to the new component, then certainly `JPanel` makes a good container.

- [Custom Painting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Sounds like the OP is calling `super.paint(g)` and then painting over the result as well. +1 for `JPanel#paintComponent`